# table structure for creating 13 rows and 31 colums

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql and sql. I want to create a table for entering 12 months and 31 days infront of it. I am not getting how structurise it.

In left hand side i should get all the months name and infront of each month i will enter 31 days each.

if i use

```
CREATE TABLE allocate (
         id INT,
         month VARCHAR(50), days INT(10)
       );
```

it will not solve my purpose.

here is the css design of the table where the data will be entered and same i need the table also in mysql

```
<table width="99%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method="post">
  <tr bgcolor="#00BFFF">
    <td><strong>Month</strong></td>
    <td width="3%">1</td>
    <td width="3%">2</td>
    <td width="3%">3</td>
    <td width="3%">4</td>
    <td width="3%">5</td>
    <td width="3%">6</td>
    <td width="3%">7</td>
    <td width="3%">8</td>
    <td width="3%">9</td>
    <td width="3%">10</td>
    <td width="3%">11</td>
    <td width="3%">12</td>
    <td width="3%">13</td>
    <td width="3%">14</td>
    <td width="3%">15</td>
    <td width="3%">16</td>
    <td width="3%">17</td>
    <td width="3%">18</td>
    <td width="3%">19</td>
    <td width="3%">20</td>
    <td width="3%">21</td>
    <td width="3%">22</td>
    <td width="3%">23</td>
    <td width="3%">24</td>
    <td width="3%">25</td>
    <td width="3%">26</td>
    <td width="3%">27</td>
    <td width="3%">28</td>
    <td width="3%">29</td>
    <td width="3%">30</td>
    <td width="3%">31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan1" id="jan1" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan2" id="jan2" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan3" id="jan3" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan4" id="jan4" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan5" id="jan5" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan6" id="jan6" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan7" id="jan7" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan8" id="jan8" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan9" id="jan9" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan10" id="jan10" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan11" id="jan11" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan12" id="jan12" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan13" id="jan13" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan14" id="jan14" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan15" id="jan15" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan16" id="jan16" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan17" id="jan17" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan18" id="jan18" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan19" id="jan19" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan20" id="jan20" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan21" id="jan21" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan22" id="jan22" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan23" id="jan23" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan24" id="jan24" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan25" id="jan25" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan26" id="jan26" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan27" id="jan27" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan28" id="jan28" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan29" id="jan29" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan30" id="jan30" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jan31" id="jan31" style="width:87%;" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Someone plz suggest me how to structurise it.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to create a table with a column named "MONTH" and 30 other columns naming from DAY1-DAY30.I don't understand the purpose of such a table. Nevertheless

The query for table creation in SQL is:

CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
....
);

For your requirement, you can use:

CREATE TABLE allocate (
         Month VARCHAR(50), Day1 INT(3),Day2 INT(3),Day4 INT(3),......................,Day30 INT(3)
       );

If you are new to SQL,i suggest you to go through the below links to understand the basics concepts of rdbms:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/